# Jquery/Javascript only running a custom function once after CSS changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using Jquery to draw lines between the cells in a web-based spreadsheet application. I accomplish this with a mixture of *background-image*, *background-position* and *background-repeat*. The entire system is working very nicely, and allows me to map between different cells in the application.

However, I'm having some trouble with my Jquery/Javascript code.

```
function draw_line(start_row, start_col, finish_row, finish_col){
    //Change CSS background properties
}

function loadData(){
    for (i = 0; i < values; i++){
        //Add element to spreadsheet - change CSS properties.

        //Draw line between the two cells
        draw_line(start_row, start_column, line, column);
    }
}

loadData();
```

The problem is that although the *for* loop should run several times for all the elements involved, it will actually only run **once**. However, if I comment out the draw_line function, the for loop executes the correct number of times, and all of the elements get placed on the spreadsheet.

I've also tried running setTimeout, but that didn't help. Anyone every experienced this sort of behavior before? (Just for reference, I'm running JQuery v1.6.4, on FF)

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your function `loadData`, where do the variables `values`, `start_row`, `start_column`, `line`, and `column` get declared and defined?

Comment: @Kevin Both methods jump 100 lines of code, so I just skimmed both of them to make the problem clearer. They're each part of an array, and they get loaded right before adding the element to the spreadsheet.

Comment: sounds like classic incorrect use of closures problem. without seeing your whole code, no one will be able to help you. you may have unknowing removed the code that causes the issues when you condensed the code for us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if this is actually causing your problem, but it's bad and risky code so you should fix it.  This line of your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < values; i++)
```

is using an implicitly declared global variable as `i`.  If any other code you are running is also doing that, then the value of `i` will get trounced and wreck your `for` loop.

Change that line to this to make `i` a local variable so nothing else can trounce it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values; i++)
```

Comment: This fixed it. Oddly enough, I nearly always use the _var_ keyword just because it's good practice, but I forgot to in this case. 

Still, doesn't change the fact that I was expecting some other behavior from the language - normally if I want to make something global, I'll declare it as global, or declare it outside my functions. 

This was a real eye-opener, and I appreciate your comment! Goes to show how loosely typed languages can creep up on you with unexpected surprises. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to investigate using `strict` mode where this would have been an error. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode for more info.